# Making a new column based on 2 other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate a new column labeled in the code as `"Sulphide-S(calc)-C_%S"`, this column can be calculated from one of two options (see below in the code). Both these columns wont be filled at the same time. So I want it to calculate from the column that has data present.  Presently, I have this but the second equation overwrites the first.

```
df["Sulphide-S(calc)-C_%S"] = df["Total-S_%S"] - df["Sulphate-S(HCL Leachable)_%S"]
df.head()

df["Sulphide-S(calc)-C_%S"] = df["Total-S_%S"]- df["Sulphate-S_%S"]
df.head()
```

Comment: Your question should be clarified by explaining why there are two options and when each of these options has to be used.

Comment: They represent the same values just measured through a different lab method. So, we want to keep the original data/method in the data frame but have a final calculated column that using both of the information. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function in pandas to create a new column based on other columns, resulting in a Series that you can add to your original dataframe. Without knowing what your dataframe looks like, the following code might not work directly until you replace the if condition with a working condition to detect the empty dataframe spot.

```
def create_sulfide_col(row):
    if row["Sulphate-S(HCL Leachable)_%S"] is None:
        val = row["Total-S_%S"] - row["Sulphate-S(HCL Leachable)_%S"]
    else:
        val = ["Total-S_%S"]- df["Sulphate-S_%S"]

    return val

df["Sulphide-S(calc)-C_%S"] = df.apply(lambda row: create_sulfide_col(row), axis='columns')
```

Comment: Thank you! I just had to adjust it abit but the set up allowed me to figure it out. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: What could be a different condition for detecting an empty dataframe? It doesn't seem no detecting when its empty and always going to the else statement. Im working with an imported excel file if that helps

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're saying correctly, the second  equation overwrites the first because they have the same column name. Try changing the column name in one or both of the "Sulphide-S(calc)-C_%S" to something else like "Sulphide-S(calc)-C_%S_A" and "Sulphide-S(calc)-C_%S_B":

```
df["Sulphide-S(calc)-C_%S_A"] = df["Total-S_%S"] - df["Sulphate-S(HCL Leachable)_%S"]
df.head()

df["Sulphide-S(calc)-C_%S_B"] = df["Total-S_%S"]- df["Sulphate-S_%S"]
df.head()
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The thing is I want them to go to the same column, but the two columns its being calculated from would never both have data at the same time, it would be one or the other. Thanks for explaining why its overwriting though!